# Cannot resolve putExtra under Bitmap Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to set the Image to the ImageView through calling a Bitmap but suddenly the line below shows `Cannot resolve putExtra`. I think there is updated syntax of this line. Is somebody knows the problem about this? I search many times but this line must be required

[image]

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 100){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.putExtra().get("BitmapImage");  //Error
        PsId.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: While you are retrieving data from _Intent_ then only _get_ is used. So for retrieving bitmap you need to use _getSerializable()_ and remove _.putExtra()_.  My suggestion is not to pass bitmap in intent. Instead pass file path

Comment: use getExtra() than putExtra()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to GET data, not PUT... just use `getExtras()` instead of `putExtra()`...

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("BitmapImage");
```

btw. avoid passing `Bitmap`s in `Intent`/`Bundle`, these are too heavy and may result in some rare crashes related to memory handling by OS... it would be better to store this bitmap in memory or cache and pass as result only reference to it (e.g. filename or some key under bitmap was stored)

Comment: thanks for your response, I've been using that line of code, but how can I achieve your suggestion that bitmap stores in memory or cache?